# Selecting only if on column value is distinct by other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a linking table with `rule_id` to `sub_rule_id` as such:

```
rule_id | sub_rule_id
---------------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
2       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 3
3       | 4
```

I want to be able to get all the `sub_rule_id`s which are linked to only one `rule_is` by `rule_id`. So if my `rule_id = 1` then I expected no rows. And if `rule_id = 2` then I should get just one. Tried to play with `distinct` and `having` and would not trouble you with a bad query.. I am sure there is an easy elegant way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group by sub_rule_id` amd set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select sub_rule_id
from tablename
group by sub_rule_id
having count(distinct rule_id) = 1
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS` if you want full rows:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename 
  where sub_rule_id = t.sub_rule_id 
  and rule_id <> t.rule_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas , where would I add `where rule_id = <some_rule_id>`  tried for both with `1` according to my example and I get my entire table minus the a 2nd row

Comment: Why the *entire table minus the a 2nd row*? What is the logic to exclude that row? Its sub_rule_id is 1 just like the 1st row. So they should both be excluded. The same for rows 4 and 5.

Comment: Thanks! Managed with the `NOT EXISTS` alternative